# How to pass a reference to a buffer as a pointer of type [sometype;1] in rust?

Tags: arrays, pointers, winapi, rust

So I'm working with `winapi-rs` crate and try to instantiate `BITMAPINFO` structure which is documented [here](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/winapi/um/wingdi/struct.BITMAPINFO.html). As it says there the field `bmiColors` is of type `[RGBQUAD; 1]`. However [Microsoft docs for same structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapinfo) claim that its a variable-sized array and also a union of 2 data types (at least to my understanding). This confused me until I came across [this GitHub page](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/issues/860) which mentioned similar matter. From my personal knowledge I recalled that Arrays and Vectors are referenced by specifying the pointer to the single element at the start and the number of elements. So I tried the following code:

```rust
pub fn load_binary_image_data(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> IMAGE {

    IMAGE::BinaryImageData {
        bitmap_info: BITMAPINFO {

            bmiHeader: BITMAPINFOHEADER {
                biSize: u32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[2..6].try_into().unwrap()),
                biWidth: i32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[18..22].try_into().unwrap()),
                biHeight: i32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[22..26].try_into().unwrap()),
                biPlanes: u16::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[26..28].try_into().unwrap()),
                biBitCount: u16::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[28..30].try_into().unwrap()),
                biCompression: u32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[30..34].try_into().unwrap()),
                biSizeImage: u32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[34..38].try_into().unwrap()),
                biXPelsPerMeter: i32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[38..42].try_into().unwrap()),
                biYPelsPerMeter: i32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[42..46].try_into().unwrap()),
                biClrUsed: u32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[46..50].try_into().unwrap()),
                biClrImportant: u32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[50..54].try_into().unwrap()),
            },

            bmiColors: if u16::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[28..30].try_into().unwrap()) <= 8 {


                let rgbquads = bytes.as_slice()[{
                    let to:  usize  = u32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[10..14].try_into().unwrap()) as usize;
                    54..to
                }].to_vec().windows(4).map(|wnd| -> RGBQUAD {
                    RGBQUAD {
                        rgbBlue: *wnd.get(0).unwrap(),
                        rgbGreen: *wnd.get(1).unwrap(),
                        rgbRed: *wnd.get(2).unwrap(),
                        rgbReserved: 0
                    }
                }).collect::<Vec<RGBQUAD>>();
                <*const [RGBQUAD;1]>::cast(rgbquads.as_ptr())
                // it can be more then 1, what to do?
            } else {
                // what to put here if the pallete is not used?
                todo!();
            },
        },

        buffer: bytes.as_slice()[
            {
                let from: usize  = u32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[10..14].try_into().unwrap()) as usize;
                let to: usize = u32::from_le_bytes(bytes.as_slice()[2..6].try_into().unwrap()) as usize;
                from..to
            }
            ].to_vec(),
    }
}
```

However the types are still mismatched despite the preformed cast. I'm not sure why. To be fair I expected the pointer to a single element array actually to be absolutely identical to the pointer to a single instance of `RGBQUAD`, however not only this wasn't the case but also the cast seem to have no effect as the error I get is:

```
<*const [RGBQUAD;1]>::cast(rgbquads.as_ptr())
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected array of 1 element, found *-ptr
   |
   = note:    expected array `[RGBQUAD; 1]`
           found raw pointer `*const _`
```

It seems that it actually expects a variable instead of a pointer. This looks very confusing as I doubt I can have an array with memory location overlapping the Vector and if I just instantiate an array from the vector first element by any means wouldn't that force the remaining variables to be dropped making it risky to read them as they probably will be some memory garbage?

Can anyone explain me what should I pass to the structure and what actually happens with the memory passed in such manner?

**Update:** for a small clarification - hardcoded indices in the code are taken from [this online guide](https://medium.com/sysf/bits-to-bitmaps-a-simple-walkthrough-of-bmp-image-format-765dc6857393).

Comment: `std::array::from_ref` seems possibly relevant here, but I'm not able to follow this code well enough to understand how to insert it.

Comment: What do you expect `<*const [RGBQUAD;1]>::cast(rgbquads.as_ptr())` to do? Do you mean `rgbquads.as_ptr().cast::<*const [RGBQUAD;1]>()`? (which is probably still not what you want)

Comment: You'd be far better off using the [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) instead of writing your own BMP parser. Don't let a *simple* online article fool you into believing that the BMP file format were simple. That article is **littered** with assumptions, that simply don't hold.

Comment: @trentcl i wanted to cast a vec pointer into an array pointer. I thought ::cast is a method of the type to be casted in not the castable. Am I wrong?

Comment: @IInspectable I'm trying to update the existing bitmap in my code using the archived bitmaps obtained in include_bytes! macro without saving them first into temp folder to increase speed and remove the questionable usage of resources. I'm not sure if I can get the bitmapinfo without saving the file in any winapi way I found so far. Is there any particular function for that I'm not aware of?

Comment: [CreateDecoderFromStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicimagingfactory-createdecoderfromstream) accepts an `IStream` interface. An `IStream` can be created from memory, using [SHCreateMemStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream), for example.