# How to acquire instance of IWICImagingFactory in winapi-rs

Tags: winapi, rust, com

So in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68795998/how-to-pass-a-reference-to-a-buffer-as-a-pointer-of-type-sometype1-in-rust) I was advised to convert byte buffers to `IStream` via `SHCreateMemStream` and use `IWICImagingFactory::CreateDecoderFromStream`. The first part already caused some complications as winapi-rs did contain an [implementation](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/winapi/um/objidlbase/struct.IStream.html) for the `IStream` but not the function itself - thankfully `winapi-rs` contained everything i needed to link it as follows:

```rs
pub type HIStream = *const IStream;

extern "system" {
    pub fn SHCreateMemStream(pbInit: *const BYTE, cbInit: UINT) -> HIStream;
}
```

.
Now I face a similar issue with the `IWICImagingFactory` class which I need to call the `CreateDecoderFromStream` method. However it according to the [documentation](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/winapi/um/wincodec/struct.IWICImagingFactory.html) it takes a `&self` parameter and similarly to the `IStream` is a trait from my understanding. How can  I obtain new instance of `IWICImagingFactory` without implementing it from scratch. I saw some talk about a function called `CoCreateInstance` and some com API specifics but that wasn't very clear as I have a very poor understanding of com API as for now.

Comment: The [WIC API Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-api) has sample code that explains how to create an `IWICImagingFactory` instance. All you need to do is transliterate this into Rust code.

Comment: That said, [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) is already significantly better at handling COM than [winapi](https://crates.io/crates/winapi), with the latter having received its last update more than a year ago. There isn't much future in winapi-rs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68879910/1889329) is close to what I'd do. The following code has two advantages:

- It produces a properly typed interface pointer (`*mut IWICImagingFactory`)
- It doesn't rely on `uninitialized()`

```rust
let mut factory: *mut IWICImagingFactory = std::ptr::null_mut();
let hr = unsafe {
    CoCreateInstance(
        &CLSID_WICImagingFactory,
        std::ptr::null_mut(),
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        &IWICImagingFactory::uuidof(),
        &mut factory as *mut *mut _ as *mut *mut _,
    )
};
```

With that you have a pointer to an `IWICImagingFactory` you can immediately use, e.g.

```rust
let mut decoder: *mut IWICBitmapDecoder = std::ptr::null_mut();
let hr = unsafe {
    (*factory).CreateDecoderFromStream(
        &mut stream,  // An IStream providing the image data
        std::ptr::null_mut(),
        options,      // Needs to be constructed elsewhere
        &mut decoder as *mut *mut _ as *mut *mut _,
    )
};
```

Error handling and resource management is mostly manual, and has been omitted from the code (you can use the [`FAILED`](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/winapi/shared/winerror/fn.FAILED.html) function to determine success or failure. Error exit still requires that you clean up by respective calls to `Release`.

The [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate provides resource management wrappers for COM interfaces, making cleanup part of stack unwinding. The net effect is that error propagation is far less verbose and manual. If you're interested, I can provide a solution based on the `windows` crate as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion from the comment I figured a way to do so by taking a look at the [WIC API Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-api) - however due to some issues on the way I wanted to add the code which allowed me to do the thing. (By no means its a good rust code - but its working for sure).

```rust
let mut pFactory: *mut c_void = uninitialized();
let hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_WICImagingFactory as *const IID,
                                              null_mut(),
                                              CLSCTX_INPROC,
                                              &IWICImagingFactory::uuidof(),
                                              &mut pFactory as *mut *mut c_void);
```

P.S. `std::mem::uninitialized` is deprecated and unsafe and apparently bad, keep that in mind.